# Do I need a separate dishing tool for building wheels with park tool TS-2.2 truing stand?

Tags: wheels, wheel-building

I'm trying to get started with some wheelbuilding. I've got a Park Tool TS-2.2 truing stand. Can I just rely on the calipers to provide a guide for centering the rim and dishing rear wheels or will I need separate dishing tool?

[image: Park Tool TS-2.2 Truing Stand]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A properly aligned TS-2 truing stand will show dish, as well as alignment.  You rarely need additional adjustment after using it.  However, if the stand is out of alignment, you may need to re-dish the wheel.

The easiest and most accurate check for TS-2 alignment is a properly dished wheel.

The best way to ensure that the wheel is properly dished, and thus an accurate alignment check, is with a dishing tool.

Bottom line, if you can afford the TS-2, a dishing tool shouldn't be a major expense, and is worth the cost, even if you only use it as a final, double check of the truing stand.

Comment: An easy way to check a stand for centering is to simply try the same wheel in both orientations -- it should be the same both ways.

Answer (score 7):

As long as you verify the centering you don't need to do separate dishing.

You will need the centering gauge: http://www.parktool.com/product/centering-gauge-1554-1

Do read the instructions and get comfortable making the centering adjustment. It's not difficult. Biggest thing to pay attention to is to SLOWLY lower the gauge into place.

Happy Riding! (and Wheel Building!)

Comment: From the link you provided: The 1554-1 will help align the TS-2 stand, but for accurate work with the TS-2, working with a dishing tool such as the WAG-4 or WAG-5 is recommended.

Comment: YMMV, but I've checked the results of several wheels I've built on a TS-2 and never needed to correct dishing.

Comment: I too have built wheels using the TS-2 and like you haven't needed to adjust dish when checked against my dishing tool. Bottom line is a dishing tool costs more or less the same as an alignment tool with a higher degree of accuracy per the manufacturers specs.

Answer (score 2):

It wouldn't hurt to buy an inexpensive dishing gauge for double-checking your builds.  I have an old Performance one that would likely cost about $15 today, and it's perfectly adequate for this duty.

However, you can get the same double-check by simply flipping the wheel around in the truing stand.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but I think if you have a misaligned stand then flipping the wheel will only show your stand is out of alignment, not that your wheel is dished correctly/incorrectly.

Comment: Flipping the wheel (for the vast majority of wheels which are symmetrical, even though "dished") will show that both that the stand is properly aligned and the wheel properly "dished".

Answer (score 2):

As said here before: A correctly aligned TS2 will be sufficient.

Beside using a dishing tool or a TS2 centering gauge, it is also possible to check the TS2 centering by flipping the wheel around. If the TS2 is centered, you will have a symmetric behavior of the gap to the rim. I.e. if you had a 1mm gap on the left while the right gap is closed and turn the wheel around, you will have a 1mm gap on the right and a closed gap on the left. Be sure that the wheel does not have any axial run-out or/and make sure that you compare the gap at the exact same position of the wheel (i.e. by marking a spoke).

If the gap is asymmetric and the TS2 needs to be centered just lower the larger gap by 1/2 times the gap difference. You can repeat this procedure after having the wheel centered with the so centered TS2 stand. Then, you center the wheel again if you needed to re-adjust the TS2 centering and so on. Finally you should have no gap on both sides for the flipped and the non-flipped position of the wheel.